# Override request.user in djangorestframework-simplejwt

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

There are two user models in my project:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    ...

class ProjectMember(UserModel):
    project = models.ForeignKey("project.Project")
```

I use `djangorestframework-simplejwt` for authorization and it gives me a `User` instance in `request.user` inside a view, here is an example:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.request import Request
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class CurrentUserView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request: Request):
        # there will be User instance
        current_user = request.user
        # Will raise an exception
        current_user.project
        # some other code here
        ...
```

I have a user, but I cannot access `project`, because it defined in `ProjectMember` and not accessible via `User`.

I found out that I can get ProjectMember instance by checking the special attribute:

```
    def get(self, request: Request):
        # there will be ProjectMember instance
        current_user = request.user.projectmember
        # I can access project now
        current_user.project
        # some other code here
        ...
```

But now I have to repeat this code in every view I use my current user. How can I override the `request.user` for it to be always a `ProjectMember` (if it is an instance of `ProjectMember`, of course)?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution while writing the question.

Override `JWTAuthentication` like this:

```
# users/auth/custom_auth.py
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication


class CustomAuth(JWTAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        user, access = super().authenticate(request)
        if hasattr(user, 'projectmember'):
            user = user.projectmember
        return user, access
```

And in `settings.py` change:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication'
    ],
}
```

to path to new class (`users/auth/custom_auth.py:CustomAuth` in my case):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'users.auth.custom_auth.CustomAuth'
    ],
}
```